# How can I use a lens from a Nikon S1 on a D3300?

Tags: nikon, lens-adapter, nikon-1

I have a Nikon S1 that I wanna use the lens from on a D3300.
Is there a adapter I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Although in this case, it's "lens brand X on camera brand X (but a different line".

Comment: @mattdm Had that thought, too. But retitling to "mount/brand X" and "mount /brand Y" could get cumbersome. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not really possible without additional optical elements. The S1 has a much shorter flange distance than the D3300, so there are adapters to use F-mount lenses on a 1-mount camera but not vice-versa. Also note that the field-of-view will change completely when you adapt between different sensor sizes, so your *everyday* lens may not be one anymore. As a matter, lenses for the S1 are unlikely to cover the image circle needed for an APS-C DSLR.

As for something for the D3300, the concept of *everyday* or *walk-around* lens is highly subjective. A good amount of people like a wide-to-mid-range zoom but some are OK with a single prime lens and others feel the need for a super-zoom. You will have to decide based on your own experience. Its is much about how you see the world and conditions you shoot in.

*Among Nikon lenses, I would opt for an AF-S 17-55mm F/2.8G as a general purpose lens but would actually prefer a Sigma 18-35mm F/1.8. A lighter weight option is the Nikkor AF-S DX 16-80mm F/2.8-4E which seems interesting but I have not tried to yet, so I have no idea how it performs. Again,  this is a personal opinion based on my shooting habits.*

Comment: Thank you for your help!  My everyday len I use on my S1 is Nikkor 10-100mm 1:4-5.6 VR this lens for me is a nice everyday, I do wanna get a macro lens for close up but thats when I'm rich lol.  My zoom is 70-300mm 1:4.5-5.6 VR  This one was my first and it does reach out lol I'm still learning as I go.   As far as the D3300 it has 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6 she wants more zoom so maybe I'll have to look for that instead of a everyday shot lens. again thank you for your help!!

Comment: You see, the 10-100 is equivalent to 27-270mm on a full-frame. Since the D3300 is APS-C, 18-180mm would cover the same range. As it turns out, Nikon has an 18-200mm which is one of the better super-zooms, it's not fantastic but such is the compromise for a long reach. At least, it performs much better than the 18-55mm kit lenses.